# np-complete and turing reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, reduction, np-complete, np, np-hard

I have some difficulties with a complexity proof : 
I work with 3 problems : A, B and C
I know :

- A-> B
- A-> C
- C -> B

A-> B meaning : if I have a "yes answer " for A , then I have a "yes answer" for B.
I know that A belongs to NP,
B and C are NP-complete. Moreover I can write an algorithm for A with a quadratic number of calls to C.
can I deduce something about the complexity of A?

To be more precise : I have a set P of k objects.
The problem A answer yes if all these objects are removed, no otherwise.
The problem C answer yes if one of these objects can be removed, no otherwise.
We have the constraint that at least one objects has to be removed at each step. In worst we make P steps.
So algorithm for A :

```
    for( i = 0 ; i < k){
    for each object p of P 
    { 
    if C(p,P)=true then 
      remove p of P}
    }
    return P = emptyset
```

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, it might be worth trying [compsci](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As you don't state that B -> A, it could be the case that A only requires yes answers in trivial cases or cases that can be determined in polynomial time while determining answers for B requires more time as more complex cases might require a Yes answer.
Shorter answer to your question: no.

Comment: Ok I understand what you means.  But the algorithm for A makes at least P calls to C , and in worst P^2 ( P is the size of the input). It is not possible to conclude that A is at least NP-hard  ?

Comment: If you know for certain that A cannot be answered more efficient than making n^2 calls to C, then A is NP-hard, but such knowledge is seldom available. You can conclude that A is NP-Hard if a NP-Complete problem can be reduced to A but not the other way around.

Comment: for me this give a lower bound for the complexity , that is to say TSP is at least as hard as Poly . To come back to my exemple I would like to have lower bound NP hard and use that A belongs to NP to conclude NP-complete